# Pass data from a browser to android

Tags: php, android, xml, database, cookies

I've been trying for days to figure out how can I pass a unique ID from a browser to the android. This is scenario that I'm try to create:

1. User scans QR code.
2. QR code directs user an url (php file on server).
3. The php files does an insert with some info.
4. User is directed to android marktet
5. User downloads app and installs it.
6. Once installed the user is supposed to be matched with the inserted information (at point 3).

My problem is that I can't seem to get anything unique from the user without prompting them to insert something (e.g an email address) first in the URL and later once the app is installed to insert the same thing again (e.g same email address) so that the data can be matched.

I've read something about creating a custom cookie that are stored on the android with a certain unique ID that refers to the inserted information in the database. I've looked into that but couldn't find anything that could get me on my way.

Next to that I thought of letting the php file save an xml or any kind of file where I can store the ID that refers to the inserted data..This too seems to be impossible.

Does any know a way how I can get around this without prompting the user to insert something unique?

**Additional information:** I'm using a jquery mobile website

Thanks

Comment: I've had a look at this, but still can't figure out how to create and write cookies to android : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885307/how-to-recognizing-the-device-from-browser-and-retrieve-unique-id

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a suggestion

If you are trying to send user information without user intraction and which can be unique I suggest you you can use IMEI number of device. Which is unique for each device.

Comment: I've looked into to that. You cannot get the users IMEI number from within a browser. You can only extract it from a native app (which I already do). I'm trying to extract something unique from the user using a browser. If that is not possible I would like to create something unique